# Embed youtube for mobile page

Tags: video, youtube, mobile-website

Is there a way to embed a link to a youtube video, so that the video will play in fullscreen on a mobile phone when the user click on the link?

The default iframe embed code will play the video inline on android phones -(

If I go to m.youtube.com they kinda does what i need, but they do it in an odd way because they generate different html and different links and protocols for viewing the video depending on which mobile phone I have.

This does make sense because the way to serve the video depend on the users phone, but is there a way for me to get some javascript/html from youtube so I can do the same thing on my own page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube has an option on the embed button called 'use old embed link' that gives you an embed code.

If you want it to serve a video according to the device, you are out of luck.

Comment: The problem is that the old embed code is flash based, so it will play inline on newer android devices. The odd thing is that m.youtube.com does exactly what I need, but that page don't use youtubes own embed system.

Comment: i belive m.youtube serves content according to your phone and youttube does not provide an api or code to use that feature on your site

Answer (score 11):

The proper way to do it seems to be like so:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Check out [the Youtube blog](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20YoutubeApiBlog%20%28YouTube%20API%20Blog%29) or [that other blog post](http://www.labnol.org/internet/embed-youtube-videos-in-html5-flash/14092/).

Now you only need to find a way to figure out which width and height to use for each device.

Comment: I'm just now digging deeper into the iframe embedding. I hadn't noticed initially, but it appears that it's still an experimental feature as of May 20th of 2011. That's what [the API reference](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html) says, and it was hinted at in the last paragraph of the blog post mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically scale the video to fit the device screen: I've been using a web application that creates the correct script for the embed code.. **http://embedresponsively.com**

It's a service that adjusts the embed code to allow YouTube videos to scale responsively.

Cant beleive this is not being managed by Google.

Comment: Thank you for very useful comment!

Comment: It's worked for me, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use a link from m.youtube.

You have to initiate it on a mobile as it will not work in a website.

It looks like this:

rtsp://v6.cache3.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQkhS9rfloZnFRMYJCAkFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYOTe4KOh-4e3TQw=/0/0/0/video.3gp

Quentin

Comment: But that breaks the youtube acceptable use policy, and it is not supported, so google may change code so this don't work anymore without any warnings. Which make it a rather bad solution -(

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with embed that set

< iframe width="611" height="450" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EzKX4LqCgCc" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen" oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen">